# Class that defines a person

Tags: java, object-oriented

I have been programming for a while, but I've only made games and less serious stuff. I want to get more serious. I would like some feedback on this class that defines a person. Structure, readability, use of static variables, etc. Please point out everything that can be improved.

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName, lastName, address;
    private int age;
    private boolean hasAddress = false;
    private boolean hasAge = false;
    private static final String NO_ADDRESS = "No address defined";

    //Constructors

    //Minimum information required
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    //All possible info
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age, String address) {
        this(firstName, lastName);
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
        hasAge = true;
        hasAddress = true;
    }

    //No address defined
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this(firstName, lastName);
        this.age = age;
        hasAge = true;
    }

    //No age defined
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String address) {
        this(firstName, lastName);
        this.address = address;
        hasAddress = true;
    }

    //Methods

    //Get-methods
    public String getName() {
        return firstName + lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        if (hasAge)
            return age;
        else
            return 0; //Return 0 if no age is defined
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        if (hasAddress)
            return address;
        else
            return NO_ADDRESS;
    }

    //Set-methods
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

Comment: You didn't test your code thoroughly before posting it here. If you had done that, you would have noticed that `getName()` just squashes together the first name and the last name, without a space in-between. This is probably not what you intended.

Comment: @RolandIllig For the purpose of getting a username, it actually could be. Anyways, I wouldn't consider the code as "not working" simply for that minor issue.

Comment: As designed you have a bug in your setAge and setAddress methods, you neglect to set your hasAge and hasAddress fields. if you start with a Person without a specified age and then call setAge subsequent calls to getAge will still return 0.

Comment: I wouldn't have age as an attribute, since it depends on the time when it's queried. However, I would have a date of birth field and have a `getAge()` method that calculates the age in runtime and returns it.

Comment: Classes are designed for a *purpose*. What is the purpose of modeling a person like this?

Comment: That's a lot of code for a 4-tuple. The class seems to allow any combination of possibly-null `firstName`,  `lastName`, `address` and `age`. What are you trying to achieve exactly with more code than a class with 4 public fields?

Comment: I would suggest, that you check the values going in. For example, age has to be a positive number. (0-200) or so. Name has to be at least one char long. And so on.

Answer (score 13):

**Design**

The problem with `getName` is already mentioned in the comments. `firstName + lastName` is at least missing a space. Note that there are multiple ways of creating a full name - you may want to leave the construction of a full name to the caller. For instance, Germans are a bit more formal and may prefer "lastname, firstname". Usually initials are also an important part of a name (and then there is title, junior/senior etc.).

Second is the age. An age is a property of a person, but it is not one that keeps constant in time. You generally store the birthday of a person. Usually the precise *day* is stored (YYYY-MM-DD), or in more complex systems just the month (YYYY-MM) or even just the year (YYYY) if the other information is unknown. This may seem strange, but not everybody knows their exact birthday. The *age* can then be calculated from that using comparison with the current date.

Related, using `0` to signify that no age is known is choosing a bad *magic value* (or sentinel). Magic values are already not recommended, but choosing a *valid age for a baby* as magic value is not a good idea at all.

Returning `return NO_ADDRESS;` is dangerous, especially if you don't have any method to indicate that `NO_ADDRESS` is indeed **not an address**. It is generally up to the caller to choose what to insert as string if no address is known, otherwise you may get packages posted to `NO_ADDRESS`. A `hasAddress` method would solve this. If you have an unknown address then you may use an `Optional` value instead. Accepting and returning an `Optional<String>` would remove the issue altogether and may bring down the number of methods and constructors. Storing the address as optional is not recommended because it cannot be serialized; probably best to use `null`, but make sure that you don't return `null`.

As you may notice, currently your `Person` instances can change completely by calling the setters. That's no good if you want to keep track of a person. This is why almost all organizations will create a unique ID for each person. That way any property can change without them becoming someone else. The ID can then represent the person in e.g. a transaction system.

**Code**

The code is generally well formed.

However there are some remarks to be made:

- fields default to `false` so there is no need to initialize them to that value; it might be a good idea to set all fields in the various constructors so that they are not forgotten;
- the `if` statement does not use braces; **always** use braces to subsequent changes do not result in unmaintainable code;
- similarly, you will probably use class instances in collections, so you need to implement the `hashCode` and `equals` methods;
- implementing `toString` is recommended for any class really.

**Ideas**

Using `set` methods is generally not a good idea. Having immutable objects often makes more sense. Other variants you may consider is having a `Map` of properties or having a factory / factory methods to create `Person` instances.

In Java, you may want to implement `Serializable` for data classes (and the static serializable UID - Eclipse will warn you about this) - that way you can more easily communicate data over a binary connection / stream. This is contended in the comments. In general, I would however try and keep in mind that you may want to be able to serialize a class in the future and - therefore - try and use serializable fields.

Comment: `Optional` is not meant to be used in fields.

Comment: Why should data classes be serializable?

Comment: And better than `Optional<Integer>`: `OptionalInt`.

Comment: The only arg I've heard for optionals not being stored in fields is that they aren't serialization by Java's jank serialization mechanism. But the serialization mechanism has been so fraught with security vulnerabilities, it's better to just pretend it doesn't exist.

Comment: "always use braces to subsequent changes do not result in unmaintainable code;" You can solve the same problem by just prohibiting multi-line `if` statements without blocks. `if (condition) return;` is totally fine IMO. You only get into dangerous [`goto fail`](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/) land when you let the body go on a second line. Just don't do that

Comment: I don't agree with some of the points you made (serializable, avoid setters... huh?), but I feel like I should upvote this answer, just for the "_**always** use braces_" alone.

Comment: @RolandIllig Looked up issues with `Optional` in field, which is generally not recommended as it messes up serialization. Serialization - the representation of the class in binary - is commonly useful for classes that represent data. I've however moved that into the comments and changed the recommendation to make sure that the class *can* be made `Serializable` in the future (which kind of automatically means a clean class design without additional references). Thanks for the comments!

Comment: Please don't implement `Serializable` just because. Effective Java (a great Java book, BTW) [explains this in detail](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-java-3rd/9780134686097/ch12.xhtml)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes To quote my comment from another thread: "[Java's serialization mechanism]'s fundamentally broken, and a consistent fountain of security vulnerabilities, so I would argue it shouldn't be used at all, ever, under any circumstances. So I don't think that's a good reason not to use Optional in args/fields. "

Comment: I don't completely agree with that. I think it is fine for (otherwise secured) internal communication / short storage etc., just not for outside interface specifications. I don't know why people think it is prudent to be used for that. I would not however frown too much if anybody used `Optional` in a field - you can always refactor when serialization is required. And in the end it is the best way of indicating the condition.

Comment: Using Optional in a field is abusing it's purpose, which is "code level static typing of possible null in method return value". Having the field be optional is pointless waste of an object allocation, since the field is internal to the class and the class knows what it stores in the field. And let me repeat this again: there is nothing evil in null checks. The evil is not knowing if a return value can be null and Optional was created to fight that evil.

Comment: Needing a field to be Optional is maybe a signal from things gone wrong elsewhere. The field is accessed from too many places? The class is too big to be easily understood by the developer? So I think it's a cure to the symptom, not the disease.

Answer (score 7):

Someone else already discussed this, but I would get rid of the boolean members `hasAge` and `hasAddress`. They don't really provide any information that the fields themselves don't provide.

An issue regarding the boolean flags is that you never update them, so they will be invalid once you use the setters. This is just a good demonstration of why you would be better off without them: they will eventually become inconsistent from the actual field state.

Instead of setting the address to a string saying no address available, just set it to an empty string or null and let the caller decide how to handle it. You could also add a `hasAddress` method that checks if the string is empty/null. An empty age could be signified as -1, assigned to a constant.

Also, instead of several different constructors, you could use the fluent builder pattern:

```
public class Person {

    private static final int EMPTY_AGE = -1;
    private static final String EMPTY_ADDRESS = "";

    private String firstName, lastName, address;
    private int age;

    public static class PersonBuilder {
        private String firstName = null, lastName = null, address = EMPTY_ADDRESS;
        private int age = EMPTY_AGE;
        public PersonBuilder firstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            return this;
        }
        public PersonBuilder lastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
            return this;
        }
        public PersonBuilder address(String address) {
            this.address = address;
            return this;
        }
        public PersonBuilder age(int age) {
            this.age = age;
            return this;
        }
        public Person build() {
            Objects.requireNonNull(firstName);
            Objects.requireNonNull(lastName);
            return new Person(firstName, lastName, address, age);
        }
    }

    public static PersonBuilder builder() {
        return new PersonBuilder();
    }

    private Person(String firstName, String lastName, String address, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return firstName + lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

Now, you can build a Person like this:

```
Person.builder().firstName("John").lastName("Doe").age(25).address("1234 Some Road").build();
```

This is especially helpful when the class has more fields.

Besides being easier to read when constructing it, the builder pattern

- Removes the possibility of mixing up constructor fields
- Allows specifying the fields in any order
- Guarantees the Person object returned will be valid. The `build` method will refuse to construct the object when required fields are missing. (This checking could alternatively be done in Person's constructor.)

Comment: Don't use sentinel values like `-1`, `""`. Arguably, you should even avoid `null`. Optional exists, and it fits the bill perfectly. What are the chances you'll use the age, forgetting that it could "not be set" (and poorly encoded as `-1`), and accidentally show a `-1 year old` age on the UI? Plus, what if this wasn't age, but some other value that could be negative? `OptionalInt` is a better choice.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I completely agree, but apparently [Java's Optional is not meant to be used for class fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24564612/507629). It also does not implement Serializable (unlike Guava's Optional which does). I think this was a poor choice on Java's part, but it is what it is. What would you suggest to denote the field is "empty" given that Optional isn't meant to be used for fields?

Comment: I guess in this case, the getters could return OptionalInt or Optional<String> and that would fit in with Optional's original intended use case. Though it still feels wrong to use sentinel values at all, as you pointed out.

Comment: Java's serialization mechanism was a poor choice on Java's part. It's fundamentally broken, and a consistent fountain of security vulnerabilities, so I would argue it shouldn't be used at all, ever, under any circumstances. So I don't think that's a good reason not to use Optional in args/fields.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica you mention the Serialization problem more than once, but in some cases serialization is _required_ — clustering / load-balancing under a Tomcat application server, for example, [requires](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/cluster-howto.html#Cluster_Basics) all session attributes to be Serializable, and you may have reason to have a Person in the Session object… saying that serialization _"shouldn't be used at all, ever, **under any circumstances**"_ is a non-starter, as there exist circumstances which _require_ it.

Comment: @StephanP I've never worked with Tomcat, but that seems no different from any other dependency. Isolate it, and play by its rules at the interface. Don't let an exception at your software boundary dictate your code style in the entire middle part.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding a boolean to check if the value is set, I suggest that you set the values with a default value; so if the value is not set, it will return it.

```java
public class Person {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String address = "No address defined";
  private int age = 0;

//Constructors

  //Minimum information required
  public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  //All possible info
  public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age, String address) {
    this(firstName, lastName);
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
  }

  //No address defined
  public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
    this(firstName, lastName);
    this.age = age;
  }

  //No age defined
  public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String address) {
    this(firstName, lastName);
    this.address = address;
  }

//Methods

  //Get-methods
  public String getName() {
    return firstName + lastName;
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public String getAddress() {
    return address;
  }

  //Set-methods
  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
  }
}
```

If you want to keep the same logic, put `-1` as the `age` and `null` to the `address` and compare the value in the getter.

```java
public class Person {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String address = null;
   private int age = -1;
   private static final String NO_ADDRESS = "No address defined";

//Constructors

   //Minimum information required
   public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
   }

   //All possible info
   public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age, String address) {
      this(firstName, lastName);
      this.age = age;
      this.address = address;
   }

   //No address defined
   public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
      this(firstName, lastName);
      this.age = age;
   }

   //No age defined
   public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String address) {
      this(firstName, lastName);
      this.address = address;
   }

//Methods

   //Get-methods
   public String getName() {
      return firstName + lastName;
   }

   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }

   public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
   }

   public int getAge() {
      if (age > 0)
         return age;
      else
         return 0; //Return 0 if no age is defined
   }

   public String getAddress() {
      if (address != null)
         return address;
      else
         return NO_ADDRESS;
   }

   //Set-methods
   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
   }

   public void setLastName(String lastName) {
      this.lastName = lastName;
   }

   public void setAge(int age) {
      this.age = age;
   }

   public void setAddress(String address) {
      this.address = address;
   }
}
```

Comment: one could also use Integer instead of int for age and default it to null as well

Comment: Don't use sentinel values like `-1`, `""`, `"No address defined"`. Arguably, you should even avoid `null`. Optional exists, and it fits the bill perfectly. What are the chances you'll use the age, forgetting that it could "not be set" (and poorly encoded as `-1`), and accidentally show a `-1 year old` age on the UI? Plus, what if this wasn't age, but some other value that could be negative? `OptionalInt` is a better choice.

Comment: I have to disagree with Alexander — Use sentinels or unset values (null) when needed, but deal with them internally, and don't return them from getters. `getAge()` then could be `public OptionalInt getAge()` where if `age < 0` then return OptionalInt.empty() and that leaves no chance of a caller accidentally using the sentinel values. I would tend to use `null`, so would have `private Integer age = null;` and getAge would `return age == null ? OptionalInt.empty() : OptionalInt.of(age)`

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding just some thoughts to explain how I would solve the problem: assuming in the simplest scenario you have two fields `firstName` and `lastName` that must be always compiled when you create a `Person` object then the simplest way is have to have a constructor that takes them as parameters:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName; 

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName  = lastName;
    }
    //getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

After you have two fields `address` and `age` that in one or more moments of the life of your objects can be null, to signal this situation to the user of your `Person` class you chose to return the values `"No address defined"` and 0 like the code below:

> ```
> private static final String NO_ADDRESS = "No address defined";
> public int getAge() {
>     if (hasAge)
>            return age;
>     else
>            return 0; //Return 0 if no age is defined
> }
> public String getAddress() {
>     if (hasAddress)
>            return address;
>     else
>            return NO_ADDRESS;
> }
> ```

I disagree with your choice because the user of your class `Person` is obliged to know the value of String `"No address defined"` to identify which address is valid and which not with `String.equals` method and for me 0 is a valid value for `age`.
My possible solution is the use of `Optional` and `OptionalInt` for address and age like my code below:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName; 
    private String address;
    private Integer age; //<-- better use int age, see note for details

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Optional<String> getAddress() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(address);
    }

    public OptionalInt getAge() {
        return OptionalInt.of(age);
    }

   //others setters and getters omitted for brevity
}
```

In this way the user of your class `Person` is forced to check if the fields address and age are set before using them:

```
Person person = new Person("firstName", "lastName");
person.setAddress("address");
person.setAge(10);
Optional<String> optAddress = person.getAddress();
if (optAddress.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println(optAddress.get());
}
OptionalInt optAge = person.getAge();
if (optAge.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println(optAge.getAsInt());
}
```

Note: following @Nathan's comment below, instead of use Integer for age field it is better to use directly int to avoid boxing and unboxing operations.

Comment: OptionalInt is meant to be used with a primitive int to avoid autoboxing and unboxing.

Comment: @Nathan Thanks, I included your comment in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As well as a missing separator, there's a missing null check here:

> ```
> public String getName() {
>     return firstName + lastName;
> }
> ```

Don't fall into the trap of assuming that all people have a first name and a last name; some have only one of those.  And some have different names in different contexts (e.g. pen-name/stage-name as well as a formal (passport) name).

Other code may be making assumptions that first name (or last name) is a "family name", but that's not certain either - read *[Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)* to pick up some other assumptions that might not be true.

Comment: That's a good point. If you do assume that a first name / last name always need to be present, then create a guard within the constructor to make sure they are not `null`. And yes, Java has terrible `null` handling, this class would be much neater in Kotlin.

Comment: This is a good start but you can go a lot farther. What is Ludwig van Beethoven's last name?  Is it "van Beethoven"? Would searching by last name for "Beethoven" then not find it? Is it "Beethoven"? If it is "Beethoven" then where does the "van" go? This notion that people have a first name and a last name that can then be concatenated to form a full name is simply false.

Comment: And what about Kim Jong-un? Kim is his first name, and also his family name; in Korea, the family name is the first name, not the last name. Is that reflected in the model? Bizarrely enough, an official of the US government referred to him as "Chairman Un" recently.

Comment: Yes, I ought to have linked to the [falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) from this answer (I complacently assumed that everybody is familiar with it, but that's obviously a falsehood itself).

Answer (score 0):

Something the other answer(s) haven't touched on.

---

## Ternary Operators

`getAge()` and `getAddress()` can both be simplified using ternary operators:

```
public int getAge() {
    return age > 0 ? age : 0;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address != null ? address : NO_ADDRESS;
}
```

Ternary works as following (in this case):

```
return (boolean condition) ? (value if true) : (value if false);
```

It's a shorter way to write the same code, and it looks a bit neater.

Also, *always* use brackets, even in a one line `if/else`. It made everything easier to read and understand, especially since you switch between the two in multiple places in your code.

Comment: Note that ternary operators are very contentious, many people would rather see them gone from the language and some style guides disallow them. The bigger problem is to leave the "sentinel" values `0` and `NO_ADDRESS` in there in the first place, without warning.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes What do you recommend to denote a field as empty? ([Java's Optional isn't meant to be used for class fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24564612/507629))

Comment: We can simplify `getAge()` further to `max(age, 0)`. In some languages, such as C# (but sadly [Java's apparently not one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223044/is-there-a-java-equivalent-to-null-coalescing-operator-in-c)), we could simplify `getAddress()` to `address ?? NO_ADDRESS`.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Interesting. Is this Java-specific, or do lots of languages' communities have a debate like this? I mostly work in Python, where ternary operators are more legible, which might be part of why I'm unfamiliar with opposition to them. (The order of the arguments is different, which is annoying when transitioning languages, but that's another story.)

Comment: Yeah, it is all about legibility. I'll try and find some pointers later...